# How to hide completely pop-out icon from ngx-doc-viewer?

Tags: angular

```
    <ngx-doc-viewer class="nginx-google" [url]="previewURL" (loaded)="onDocLoad()" disableContent="popout-hide" 
                viewer="google" [googleCheckContentLoaded]="true" [googleMaxChecks]="200" [googleCheckInterval]="1000" >
            </ngx-doc-viewer>
```

I want to Hide completely pop-out icon from viewer